# Spring @Transactional wont rollback after putting aspect around method

Tags: spring, transactions, rollback, transactional, aspect

I have two transactional methods one inside other. When around aspect is not set around methodA Transactional anotation work well. After calling methodA we call methodB, methodB write something in DB, then we return in methodA, throw an exception and then methodB roolback.
But when I put my aspect around methodA, methodB wont rollback. I cant figure out what is happening there. I tried many combination of propagation attributes but none seems to work.
Thanks in advance.
I use Spring 2.5.4

I have this configuration in applicationContext.xml :

```
<!-- Aspect -->
<bean id="logAspect" class="LoggingAspect" />
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="aspectLoggging" ref="logAspect" >
        <aop:pointcut id="testAround" expression="execution(* methodA(..))" />
        <!-- @Around -->
        <aop:around method="logProcess" pointcut-ref="testAround" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

My LoggingAspect class is like this :

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
    public void logProcess(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        <!-- some code before -->
        try {
            Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(e.getMessage());
            <!-- some code here -->     
        }   

        <!-- some code after -->
    }
}
```

MethodA is like this :

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public something methodA() throws Exception {
    methodB();
    ...
    throw new Exception("message ...");
    ...
}
```

MethodB is like this :

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void methodB() throws Exception {
    <!-- insert something in db --<
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276037/transaction-required-propagation-in-spring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your aspect if flawed

1. You must always return Object from an around aspect
2. Never catch and swallow an exception

```
public void logProcess(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable  { ... }
```

Your aspect has a `void` method this should be `Object` and you should always return the result of the call to `proceed()`.

Next you are catching and swallowing the exception if any would occur, you should always rethrow the exception if you don't this breaks proper tx, management.

Your aspect should look more liks this.

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
    public Object logProcess(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        <!-- some code before -->
        try {
            Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
            <!-- some code after -->
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(e.getMessage());
            <!-- some code here -->     
            throw e;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it works exactly as I wanted. Thank you for your prompt and detailed reply.