# Passing parameter to same aspect method for different pointcut from xml

Tags: java, spring, parameter-passing, aop, aspect

Is it possible to use same aspect method for multiple pointcuts but with different parameters given from xml?
Something like this(1 and 2 are parameters) :

```
<!-- Aspect -->
<bean id="logAspect" class="LoggingAspect" />
<aop:config>
<aop:aspect id="aspectLoggging" ref="logAspect" >
    <aop:pointcut id="testAround" expression="execution(* methodA(..))" />
    <aop:pointcut id="testAroundC" expression="execution(* methodC(..))" />

    <!-- @Around -->
    <aop:around method="logProcess(1)" pointcut-ref="testAround" />
    <aop:around method="logProcess(2)" pointcut-ref="testAroundC" />
</aop:aspect>
```

When I call methodA I want logProcess method to output 1 
and when I call methodC I want logProcess method to output 2

My logProcess method :

```
public Object logProcess(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {}
```

[Spring @Transactional wont rollback after putting aspect around method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755006/spring-transactional-wont-rollback-after-putting-aspect-around-method)

Comment: I don't think so. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because I have multiple processes(methods) that have their id-s witch i want to write in DB  before and after execution of those methods. and I dont want to rewrite same method but with different parameters (logProcess) for every method I want to wrap around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure not.

However you can generally achieve this kind of functionality by utilising the `ProceedingJoinPoint` object that you have as a parameter:

```
public Object logProcess(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable

    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();
    if(method.getName().equals("methodA")) {

    }
    //etc..
```

Comment: Well, this is very useful. I can connect these id-s with method names in DB and I don't need multiple if statements. Thanks!